# Make gRPC call from Go client with TLS - GCP Cloud Function

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-functions, grpc-go

I'm working on a few different GCP Cloud Functions that need to communicate with my backend using gRPC. The backend services are encrypted behind TLS, and only accessible through it (the APIs can't be called without TLS). The server is working perfectly fine as expected, I have a UI that is also calling the same APIs, and those work perfectly fine so the server is properly set up.

Given this setup, I'm struggling to figure out how I can call my backend APIs through gRPC from my GCP Cloud Functions. I know i can call `grpc.Dial("some_endpoint", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(<credentials>))`, however I don't know how to get `credentials` to pass to the `grpc.WithTransportCredentials` method.

I'm not sure what other information you may need, but whatever it may be, I will be happy to provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this [gRPC authentication mechanisms](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) guide that provides examples on supported auth mechanisms such as SSL/TLS integration, ALTS and Token-based authentication with Google.

Sample implementation:

1. No encryption or authentication

- Client

```js
conn, _ := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
// error handling omitted
client := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)
// ...
```

- Server

```js
s := grpc.NewServer()
lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:50051")
// error handling omitted
s.Serve(lis)
```

2. With server authentication SSL/TLS

- Client

```js
creds, _ := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile(certFile, "")
conn, _ := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
// error handling omitted
client := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)
// ...
```

- Server

```js
creds, _ := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(certFile, keyFile)
s := grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))
lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:50051")
// error handling omitted
s.Serve(lis)
```

3. Authenticate using Google service account

```js
pool, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
// error handling omitted
creds := credentials.NewClientTLSFromCert(pool, "")
perRPC, _ := oauth.NewServiceAccountFromFile("service-account.json", scope)
conn, _ := grpc.Dial(
    "greeter.googleapis.com",
    grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds),
    grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials(perRPC),
)
// error handling omitted
client := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The issue with the 1. is that my backend only supports SSL/TLS, so I can't pass `insecure.NewCredentials()`. The issue with 2. is that I'm going to be deploying to GCP Cloud Functions, so I won't have access to a certificate (unless it would be ok to have my cert in my GitHub repo, though I'm hesitant to do that). That leaves 3., which I cannot test on my dev machine, as it's windows, and so my question would be - is `x509.SystemCertPool` accessbile on GCP Cloud Functions?